# how to make header fixed in next.js with useEffect

Tags: next.js, react-hooks

i am working on next.js web, what I want to make is to have the header become fixed when the page is scrolling down.

I am still quite new to the concept of useEffect, so did an experiment as below

```
export function MainNav({}: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>) {
  const [scrolledFromTop, setScrollTop] = useState(false);

  const condition = scrolledFromTop ? 'absolute' : 'fixed'

  useEffect(() => {
    window.pageYOffset >= 50 ? setScrollTop(true) : setScrollTop(false);
 }, [])

   <header className={` z-50 bg-white bg-opacity-80 shadow-sm backdrop-blur-sm w-full ${condition}`} >
    </header>
  )
}
```

but it doesn't work out, wondering how would I design it in the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening since you have passed an empty dependency array of `useEffect`. Due to this, the useEffect callback runs only once when the component is mounted and the value of `scrolledFromTop` does not update.
To fix this, you can use a variable that updates on scroll in the dependency array.

But a straightforward way is to use event listener and update `scrolledFromTop` in the callback like this:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    window.pageYOffset >= 50 ? setScrollTop(true) : setScrollTop(false);
});
```

**Edit:**
Don't forget to remove event listener  otherwise it might lead to unexpected error or memory leaks.
In order to attach the event listener when component mounts and remove when component unmounts, you can use `useEffect` hook:

```js
//register event listener when component mounts
useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
    // the function returned from here will run on unmounting
    return function() {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
    }
}, []);

function scrollHandler(event){
   window.pageYOffset >= 50 ? setScrollTop(true) : setScrollTop(false);
}
```